# Java Garbage Collection stalls all Java processes

Tags: java, garbage-collection

We're running multiple instances of a server process on one linux box. The box has 8 cores and 16gb of RAM. I'm starting up each process with the -Xincgc option, using Java 1.6.

We have various timers instrumented throughout the application that track the time to complete various tasks. When garbage collection happens, I notice that every java process on the box prints out that whatever task it was running at the time was slow.

It's not stalling for a long time, maybe 100-300ms or so, but latency is a huge factor for this. It's also not stalling constantly, just periodically.

When garbage collection is happening does it stop any java process from getting any time? If so, is there any way around this? Should I be using different GC options?

UPDATE:

Just to be clear, I'm not worried about one process stalling while GC is happening. I can tweak settings or optimize for that case. I'm just wondering why EVERY running Java process seems to stall at the same time when I thought they were more or less independent.

Comment: GC shouldn't really stall all the processes. Also, you should read through the [GC tuning guide](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/gc-tuning-6-140523.html). The default garbage collector for Java 6 should be the parallel GC, which is optimised for throughput, not pause time. The concurrent collector might be a better fit.

Comment: You may want to consider object pooling.  That would be one way to reduce the amount of GC that is happening.

Comment: @Guaranteed: you are running independent JVMs and when one JVM performs a full GC every single JVM is affected?  Is this what you're describing?

Comment: @TacticalCoder Yes. That seems to be the case. It also never seems like the CPU is completely maxed out either. At least not across all 8 cores.

Comment: @Guaranteed: that seems like a weird behavior.  Do you have a test environment where you can reproduce this and do experiments?  Could you try to run the JVM from separate user accounts (heck, you could even try with **different** JVMs running simultaneously) and set the CPU affinity for each JVM?  For example only allow each JVM to use a max of 5 cores (evenly distributed across your 8 cores) and see if you still see that weird behavior when one JVM performs a full GC?

Comment: @TacticalCoder Forgive my lack of knowledge on this issue, but is there a difference between multiple JVMs and multiple processes? I'm running multiple processes by running one main java process from command line using java command, and then launching and controlling multiple processes from there using Java's ProcessBuilder class.

Comment: @Guaranteed: Wait... You are spawning more JVMs from one JVM by calling ProcessBuilder?  Could you try to modify your *ProcessBuilder* call as  to not directly call Java but call a shell script that would  fork the subsequent JVMs (*e.g.* "nohup java args &") ?  Would that work in your case?  That said I somehow don't think that launching more JVMs from *ProcessBuilder* is a good design...

Comment: @TacticalCoder Would I still be able to read output for those processes by doing it that way? The reason is works that way is that the main process is a Launcher that is responsible for spawning and launching multiple children. It then monitors those to make sure they are functioning, and can kill or restart them as necessary. I will definitely try and see if doing that changes the behavior though.

Comment: @Guaranteed: honestly I hate having to deal with spawned processes input/output streams from Java... I think redirecting the output to files and parsing the files is way less error prone (but it's more work). So, yup, you *could* do it, but that would require using files instead of output stream for IPC / heartbeat monitoring (you're doing a kind of *heartbeat* if I understand you correctly).  But, yup, I really suggest trying anyway, just to see if the behavior persist or not.

Answer (score 3):

when you use `-Xincgc`, as per this [sun documentation](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/gc-tuning-5-138395.html#1.1.%20Types%20of%20Collectors%7Coutline)

The concurrent low pause collector: this collector is used if the `-Xincgc` ™ or `-XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC` is passed on the command line. The concurrent collector is used to collect the tenured generation and does most of the collection concurrently with the execution of the application. **The application is paused for short periods during the collection**.

You may need to consider other alternatives like Throughput Collector. Above documentation has good description on when, which collector will be useful.

Comment: If I read that documentation right, the throughput collector is even less suitable for a low pause requirement - ALL the collectors will pause sometimes, they just differ in how long every pause will be and how much of the total execution time will be spent in pauses. AFAIK, the throughput collector will have longer individual pauses, but they'll take up less time in the end. The incremental collector will have more shorter pauses that will add up to more time spent stalled.

Comment: Also, the guide you linked to is for Java 5.0. Which garbage collectors are available / selected by default is one thing that changes between releases of the HotSpot VM, so you should definitely use the most current relevant documentation when talking about them.

Answer (score 3):

Java v 1.6 is supposed to be smart and work out which kind of GC is the best.

I'd recommend reading this: [Garbage collection in Java 6](http://java.sun.com/performance/reference/whitepapers/6_performance.html#2.2.1)

Summary: try either of these (but not both):

- -XX:+UseParallelGC
- -XX:+ExplicitGCInvokesConcurren

Answer (score 2):

The problem you are encountering is a 'Full Garbage Collection', also known as a 'Stop the world GC'.  When this occurs you java app basicly stops working.  Check this thread for some pointers:

[Tuning garbage collections for low latency](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2781797/tuning-garbage-collections-for-low-latency)

Answer (score 0):

If you use a tool like JConsole to view your memory activity you will see that garbage collection is generally a weighty activity. You may want to do some profiling to see if there are other bottlenecks involved. Also, most of the garbage collection algorithms have quite a few configuration options available to them.

Lastly, I remember a situation we dealt with quite a while ago led us to find that having your min and max memory settings closer together was helpful (at least in our case). It caused more frequent garbage collection but they were not as intrusive.

Hope this helps.