# Java Garbage Collection Time?

Tags: java, performance, garbage-collection

I have a very performance sensitive application in Java. (I know I should actually use C or something else. But it's Java now.) I'm trying to avoid creating and throwing away objects. Now I need to know how much garbage collecting is going on still.

**How can I find out ?**

If possible I would like to have a sort of number in milliseconds or nanoseconds something that doesn't require installation of more software.

Comment: Just a heads up that C is not hands-down better than Java - it depends on how you compare them. [This is a good comparison I found](http://www.azulsystems.com/blog/cliff/2009-09-06-java-vs-c-performanceagain), the bottom line is that C is better than Java for memory footprint and for numerically intensive programs, while Java has better multi-threading support.  A research paper I read several years ago found that (if you let Java's heap grow to 4x the size of the C heap) there was no performance difference between the two languages for many Sourceforge programs.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Tuning garbage collections for low latency](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2781797/tuning-garbage-collections-for-low-latency)

Answer (score 9):

Or you can let JVM print the GC activity.. These settings I have:

```
-verbose:gc -XX:+PrintGCTimeStamps -XX:+PrintGCDetails -XX:+PrintTenuringDistribution -Xloggc:logs/gc.log
```

GC activity is printed to a file *logs/gc.log*..

Answer (score 7):

You can use tools like [VisualVM](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/visualvm/monitor_tab.html) to monitor application activity. Make sure you are using appropriate GC alogorithms.

Oracle JVM provides multiple types of Garbage Collectors:

- The throughput collector
- The concurrent low pause collector
- The incremental (sometimes called train) low pause collector:

Read more on these collectors [here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/gc-tuning-5-138395.html#1.1.%20Types%20of%20Collectors%7Coutline).

Comment: +1 Note: for low GC programs, VisualVM will create more garbage than your application.  For this I use YourKit, which is not free.  I would start with VisualVM.

Comment: There is also a plugin for VisualVM called VisualGC which shows what is happening for each heap space in real time.  https://blogs.oracle.com/klc/entry/visualgc_plugin_for_visualvm

Answer (score 2):

You can use [VisualVm](http://visualvm.java.net/) for this, it is exactly what you need.
As you can see below you have GC activity which is very useful:

[image]

Beside the GC Activity you have a lot of details there like : heap usage, cpu usage, object instances usage etc.

Answer (score 1):

[Jprofiler](http://www.ej-technologies.com/products/jprofiler/overview.html)  ,which Enables both memory profile to assess memory usage and dynamic allocation leaks and CPU profiling to assess thread conflicts.